# RAILS - HOW TO COMPARE VALUES BY ARRAY INDEX

Tags: ruby

I'm new to rails and I was wondering how I compare the first value of array "a" if it is greater than the first value of array "b"?

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 2, 1]
```

How do I check if `a[0]` is greater than `b[0]`.

Comment: This has  nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: It's literally `a[0] > b[0]` with `>` being the "greater than" operator. This isn't even Ruby specific, it works that way in most common programming languages.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE]" and all their linked pages. We expect to see your attempt to solve this prior to asking for help. Without evidence of your effort it looks like you didn't try and want us to 
find a reference, tutorial, or write code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-first) method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 2, 1]

a.first > b.first #=> false
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]", especially the section "Answer well-asked questions", and its linked pages. Instead of answering poorly asked questions, vote to close. That helps preserved the quality of the site and avoids wasting effort when you've answered and later the question is closed. In addition, your answer is considered code-only; See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". This might be technically correct but it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be THE answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.